# Dynamic checkboxes on classic asp page

Tags: html, asp-classic, dynamic-controls

I am having some trouble dynamically creating checkboxes on a .asp page. I am using the following code indside of a  cell on a table (note - rsMaint is a recordset):

```
<%
    if not rsMaint.EOF then     
    rsMaint.moveFirst

    index = 1
%>
    <%
        do while not rsMaint.EOF                
    %>
    <% 
        Response.Write(CreateLabel(rsMaint.fields.getValue("name"),0) )         
        Response.Write("<INPUT type=""checkbox"" id=cb" & index & " value=" & rsMaint.fields.getValue("template_id") & ">")

            rsMaint.moveNext()  
            index = index + 1
            loop
    %>
```

This works find to create my checkboxes and I can view source and see that they have the id's cb1, cb2, cb3 etc. I get an object does not exist error if I try to do:

```
if cb1.getChecked() = true Then
...
end if
```

Comment: What is `cb1.getChecked()` supposed to mean? Where do you call it?

Comment: Also, can you tell us what `rsMaint` is (because, the way you use it, it's not ADO)?

Comment: getChecked() is the method I have seen used on other pages to check if a checkbox is checked though I see now that is likely a method belonging to the interdev design time checkbox. Also rsMaint is a ADO recordset that gets values from a select statement

Comment: @curtis: What makes you think that there would be a `cb1` object? Seems there is a step missing somewhere.

Comment: When my page loads it has the desired checkboxes created and there is one with an id of cb1. I can access checkboxes that I drop down with my toolbox like this. In asp.net I would use the FindControl() method to find a a control by its ID. What is the correct way to do this in asp?

Comment: Uhm, no. There is no *magical framework* that creates these controls for you in classic ASP. You have to evaluate the `Request()` collection's contents manually to find out the state of form fields after a form is posted. And this works by name, not by id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%
  rsMaint.moveFirst
  index = 1

  While Not rsMaint.EOF                
    val = rsMaint.fields.getValue("template_id")

    Response.Write(CreateLabel(rsMaint.fields.getValue("name"),0) )         
    Response.Write("<INPUT type=""checkbox"" id="""cb" & index & """" & _
                   " name="""checkbox_" & index & """" & _
                   " value=""" & Server.HTMLEncode(val) & """>")

    rsMaint.moveNext()  
    index = index + 1
  Wend
%>
```

Later, when a user posted back the form, you can do

```
<%
  If Request("checkbox_1") > "" Then 
    ''# ...
  End If
%>
```

Note that you must **NEVER** output a data value without HTML-encoding it first.